# Trying to hide django secret key, but getting error when deploying in PythonAnywhere

Tags: django, security, github, pythonanywhere, secret-key

I'm trying to deploy a django project. I hid the secret key putting it in a file called **.env** and added it to **.gitignore**, so I have django's secret key only locally, and not in the git repository. But when I try to deploy the project in PythonAnywhere, an error occurs because there is no secret key in the repository (there is no file from where the server could read the secret key).

So I understand that it's not good to hard code the key, but how would I do to get a secret key for deployment?

I shouldn't have any secret key in the git repository, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I shouldn't have any secret key in the git repository, right?

Right.

> So I understand that it's not good to hard code the key, but how would I do to get a secret key for deployment?

The secret key can be stored as an environment variable or in a file that deploys alongside your project. Both options would have to be done through your host. Here's a Pythonanywhere suggestion for a file that deploys alongside your project: https://www.pythonanywhere.com/forums/topic/14207/

Comment: I'm not sure if I got it right. With "host" you mean the server on PythonAnywhere (or any other like AWS)? And thus I should then have two different secret keys, one of them locally in my computer and another one in PythonAnywhere? Is that right?

Comment: Yes host is where your server is running to be accessed by the internet. Could be PythonAnywhere, AWS, Azure, Google cloud...
You don't have to have two different secret keys - Django only uses one. You have two choice/options/possibilities of where you could put that one secret key.

Comment: And here's a link to the relevant [PythonAnywhere documentation](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/environment-variables-for-web-apps/) page.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I got it. I created an environment variable on the host to store the secret key. I didn't reply here because I got another problem and was trying to solve it, but I think it has been two days now that I'm stuck with it. But again, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a separate .env file on PythonAnywhere to store a separate secret key. The .env file also a good place to store PythonAnywhere database passwords etc.
Having a different file with different values locally and on PythonAnywhere makes sense from a security perspective. Don't forget to update your PythonAnywhere .gitignore file to include it if you ever upload to your git repository from PA!

You can create a new .env file in your project directory via the PA files section, and, using your local .env file as a base, generate a new key value either by:

```
$ python -c "from django.core.management.utils import get_random_secret_key; print(get_random_secret_key())"
```

or use a web tool like https://djecrety.ir/

Comment: I didn't imagine the possibility of storing another things like database passwords in a .env file. It's good to know that's another possibility. Thanks! :)